# All tools suddenly disappearing right after I add an object

Tags: 3d-view, interface, bones, edit-mode, eevee-render-engine

Here you can see when I selected a rig, the rotate ball won't show up.
[image: I arleady selected the rotate tool as seen in the image.]
Any idea why did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the gizmos turned off in the viewport!
[image: Gizmos off]

Try turning them back on!
[image: Gizmos on]